# Razor syntax incorrect?? jquery function onchange of Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to call a jquery function through the onchange event of this DropDownList. I've googled and googled and can't find out why my razor syntax is wrong. Help please?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, (List<SelectListItem>)Type, new { @onchange = "reloadDial(" + @Model.AppID, @Model.LoginID, @Model, @ViewBag.Edit + ")"})
```

The error is in the last part. **@ViewBag.Edit + ")"}**) Error is "Invalid anonymous type declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the problem is you're trying to concatenate some arguments for the `javascript` `function`. Your arguments are not in a `string`, so the compiler thinks you're trying to add more `properties` to the anonymous `object`.

So...

```
"reloadDial(" + @Model.AppID, @Model.LoginID, @Model, @ViewBag.Edit + ")"
```

should be:

```
"reloadDial('" + @Model.AppID + "','" + @Model.LoginID + "','" +  @Model + '",'" + @ViewBag.Edit + ")"
```

Comment: Also, where you have `@onchange`, you only need `onchange`.  The reason you will sometimes see `@class` in such anonymous declarations is that `class` is a keyword in c#, and thus can't be used without prefixing it with `@`